# Designing Templates for Web Forms in c#

Tags: asp.net

I have got to work on developing a data entry form(Web based) with rich look GUI.Im new to such development. So please let me know if there are any online templates available or please guide me how to design forms with rich look-and-feel.

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Also your question is quite vague.

Comment: (1) Google or Bing "ASP.net", (2) "Javascript", (3) "Ajax" (4) "javascript frameworks" (5) Then [exert some effort on your own](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and if you have specific questions, then post on SO.

Comment: Hi christian Dietz..I keep trying  for the design..Lemme explain in detail if its vague for u..I need to design a Web Form (with rich GUI look). I have never worked on Web form designs but i have to design a web form ASAP.so looking for a design template.

Comment: Hi EdSF...I keep Googling for such design templates..not getting it..